# Jobs Message View Doesn't work properly in Safari

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, safari, jobs-messages

The Jobs site won't allow me to view sent messages or anything besides the default inbox when using Safari.

[image: Folder selection under safari]

Comment: I repro this on Safari 9.1.3. This is a supported browser, so this is definitely a bug.

Comment: Could you please tell me the OS you're using, along with the Safari version?

Comment: I'm not at that computer right now but I will look it up when I get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now fixed.

It should also be much faster as there's now one less page load when changing message category.

Thank you for your report!

---

**Note:**

You most likely hit [this webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24175), which might affect you in other ways, or on other sites.  For this reason (and for security patches), I highly recommend upgrading your browser, if possible.

That being said, there was *another* bug in our code. Since it's now fixed, the specific issue you reported should be gone.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! I enjoy the site a lot.